# redirection with balancer (VIP https) to play (tomcat HTTP)

Tags: playframework

I have the following architecture:

> LOAD BALANCER (VIP https) <-> PLAY (over TOMCAT http)

When i call an url on VIP https (example: https://www.foo.com) it is redirected to TOMCAT http (example: http://www.bar.com)
but when play handle the response and do a redirect, it redirects to HTTP and not HTTPS.

Is there a way to use the entry base url from the VIP and not the local base url?

I find a trick by doing following dirty method in play controller, but it leads to infinite loop:

```
   @Before
   public static void dirtySecureTrick() {
      if (Play.mode.isProd() && !request.secure) {
         redirect("https://" + request.domain +request.url);
      }      
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://www.playframework.org/modules/reverseproxy-0.1/home

"allows developers to configure web applications to
automatically switch between the HTTP and HTTPS protocols per page
when used behind a front end Reverse-Proxy"